# Determine min and max of the following expressions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $a_1,\; ...\;, a_n$ and $b_1,\; ...\;, b_n\in \mathbb R$ be positive real numbers.

Find 
$$
max \;(a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... + a_nx_n)
$$ and
$$
min \;(a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... + a_nx_n)
$$ over $x_1, \; ...\;, x_n\in \mathbb R$, $ $ subject to $b_1x_1^2 + b_2x_2^2 +\;...\;+b_nx_n^2 = 1$.

I don't even know where to start. This was given as a linear algebra problem, and we haven't covered Lagrange multipliers. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!